# Asociar un evento que valide cuando un texto son 5 dígitos

Tags: javascript

**¿Por qué no cambia la propiedad del .error o del color?**

```
Cod.Postal:
<input type="text" name="codigo" id="idcodigo" maxlength="5" onchange="validarCP();" onKeyPress="return soloNumeros(event);">
```

**El CP admitirá un máximo de 5 dígitos.** En caso contrario:

- El fondo cambia a color rojo.
- Se mostrará un mensaje.
- Cuando recupere el foco o se introduzca un CP correcto, cambiará el
  color del fondo.

**Código JavaScript**

```
//Solo permite introducir numeros.
function soloNumeros(e){
    var key = window.event ? e.which : e.keyCode
    return (key >= 48 && key <= 57)
}



function validarCP(){
    //Eliminamos la clase error asignada al elemento CP.
    document.getElementById("idcodigo").className="";
    var valor = document.getElementById("idcodigo").value;
    var patron = /^\d{5}$/;
    if (patron.test(document.getElementById("idcodigo").value) && (!isNaN(valor))){
        document.getElementById("idcodigo").className="correcto";   
        return true;
    }else{
        //Situamos el foco en el campo idcodigo y le asignamos la clase error.
        alert("El código debe tener al menos 5 digitos.\n");
        document.getElementById("idcodigo").focus();
        document.getElementById("idcodigo").className="error";  
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: En la misma pregunta dice **(1)** "un máximo de 5 dígitos" **(2)** "al menos 5 dígitos" y **(3)** tu expresión regular sólo acepta *exactamente* 5 dgitos.... ¿Cuál de todas es?

Comment: @omaza1990, se que tu intención es aprender pero me da la impresión de que estás haciendo preguntas para resolver tus ejercicios, lo digo más que nada por tus tres últimas preguntas, (que he podido apreciar) las veo como ejercicios, te lo digo porque debes intentarlo tu a pesar de que no te salga, los mejores ejercicios son los que se propone uno a medida que va aprendiendo a programar. ;)

Comment: De eso creo que se trata, de plantearse un ejercicio real o ficticio y si una vez dado varias vueltas no se consigue (con código demostable) pues pedir una ayuda para ver dónde está el error. Creo.

Comment: @omaza1990: No se deben incluir etiquetas como "EDITADO" en el título de la pregunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supongo que quieres que tu función se ejecute cuando se cambia algo en el imput, entonces puedes llamarla de esta manera:

```
<input type='text' id='idcodigo' onchange='validarCP()'>
```

Si ya estas agregandole la clase error, puedes desde el CSS poner el color rojo a esa clase, así cuando pierda la clase 'error' volverá a su color predeterminado:

```
.error{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```js
function validarCP(){
    // Eliminamos la clase error asignada al elemento CP.
    document.getElementById("idcodigo").className="";
    var valor = document.getElementById("idcodigo").value;
    var patron = /^\d{5}$/;
    if (patron.test(document.getElementById("idcodigo").value) && (!isNaN(valor))){
        document.getElementById("idcodigo").className="correcto";   
        return true;
    }else{
        //Situamos el foco en el campo idcodigo y le asignamos la clase error.
        alert("El código debe tener al menos 5 digitos.\n");
        document.getElementById("idcodigo").focus();
        document.getElementById("idcodigo").className="error";  
        return false;
    }
}
```

```css
.error{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='idcodigo' onchange='validarCP()'>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Aquí te dejo 2 rutina que cumple con tus requerimientos:**

1.- Validando con código ***javaScript*** tal como lo solicitas, y.
2.- Validando con código ***HTML5*** y que también cumple con tus requerimientos:

Ejemplo con código ***JavaScript***:

```js
function myOnLoad() {
 cargar_provincias();
}
function validarCPonFocus(e) {
 //Elimina la Clase error al hacer foco en el campo
 e.classList.remove("error");
}
function validarCP(e){
 var patron = /^\d{5,5}$/;
 if ( !patron.test(e.value) ) {

 // le asignamos la clase error.
 e.classList.add("error");
 alert("El código Postal debe contener minimo 5 digitos numericos");
 return false;
 }
}
```

```css
.error {
 background-color:#f00;
}
```

```html
Cod.Postal:<input type="text" name="codigo" id="idcodigo" maxlength="5" onchange="validarCP(this)" onBlur="validarCP(this)" onFocus="validarCPonFocus(this)">
```

Ejemplo con código ***HTML5*** (es ideal para validar formularios, escribes mucho menos!! ;))...:

```js
function myOnLoad() {
 cargar_provincias();
}
```

```html
<form>
Cod.Postal (type=text):<br><input type="text" name="codigo" size="5" minlength="5" maxlength="5" title="El código Postal debe contener minimo 5 digitos numericos" required pattern="^\d{5,5}$">
<br>
<br>
Cod.Postal (type=number):<br><input type="number" name="numero" min="10000" max="99999" title="El código Postal debe contener minimo 5 digitos numericos" required>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Comment: Lo malo que me deja escribir letras, sólo debería permitir dígitos del 0 al 9.

Comment: he modificado la versión **html5** para que valide campos de: texto y numérico, y recuerda: califica la respuesta que mas se adecue a tus requerimientos. Saludos!! ;))...

Comment: Revisa nuevamente

Comment: funciones.js:49 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: Con cual navegador estas trabajando?

Comment: Chrome, aunque sé que es mejor en consola el Firefox. Pero es una mania que tengo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58755/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-fwbasic).